# cakephp how refer to object calling/rendering a view

Tags: cakephp

I have variables in each controller, and I have been passing them to the view with $this->set for every function.  It's repetitive.  How can I simply refer to the object that renders the view and thus refer to its variable?

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you provide a little code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your beforeFilter or beforeRender. So if you have the same set of variables you need to set for every function, just add this to the top of your controller:

```
function beforeRender() {
   parent::beforeRender();
   $this->set('var_name1', $this->my_var1);
   $this->set('var_name2', $this->my_var2);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks for bringing that to my attention. You are correct. I added `$this` to the variables.

Comment: Note that `$my_var` is local to beforeRender. So you'd have to either put set it in this function or set it elsewhere as a property of that controller, i.e. `$this->my_var`

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain the line:  `parent::beforeRender();` including the double colon?

Comment: This is in case you have beforeRender in your app_controller.php file. It will include that. Without parent::beforeRender, you are overriding the method.